# Adding line numbers to a PDF

Tags: pdf

I am looking for a script, web service or program that can add line numbers to a PDF.  Any license, price and operating system is fine.

Ideally, it should support PDF with 2 column text layout.

Comment: Are you looking to add line numbers to an existing pdf or a generated one? If existing then what is the source(s), if generated then by what mechanism?

Comment: Do you have a sample PDF file?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18760/add-page-and-line-numbers-to-a-pdf

Comment: @SteveBarnes Existing PDF,  which was generated with latex but I don't have the source

Comment: @iPDFdev e.g. http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N16-1062